# Equivalent resistance problem

Tags: resistance, electricity, homework

[image]

By the use of symmetry, I have found that equal currents will flow through opposite edges like A-C and C'A', but still, the use of kirchoff's current and voltage laws lead to four equations in four variables which I am not able to solve, neither I am sure that the four equations which I have created are independent since I have used symmetry in dividing currents. I think there should be some shorter method to solve this, can any one please give a hint?(Not complete solution)

Comment: Ah... I remember this cube... This question is pretty common within the electrical engineering curriculum so I'm pretty sure you can find this question somewhere online.

Comment: But I am a senior secondary school student. I have searched on Google but didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't see why the question needs to state what the potential difference is between A and A' to be able to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corners form neutral point for 3 resistors in wye.  You should be able to convert them to delta and combine resistors (going back-and-forth between delta and wye) until you simplify enough to solve.  See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).